# Ruby - Mongoid - cannot query date range, error: keys must be strings or symbols

Tags: ruby, mongoid, where-clause

The following query does not work and it keeps giving a weird error:
***keys must be strings or symbols***

```
Session.where(:created_at.gte => (Date.today - 30), :created_at.lte => (Date.today).first
```

Here is the content of the query when I inspect it:

```
:::::::::::::::::: # selector: {#=>Wed, 04 Jan 2012, #=>Thu, 05 Jan 2012},
options: {},
class: Session,
embedded: false>
:::::::::::::::::: # selector: {#=>Wed, 04 Jan 2012, #=>Thu, 05 Jan 2012},
options: {},
class: Session,
embedded: false>
:::::::::::::::::: # selector: {#=>Wed, 04 Jan 2012, #=>Thu, 05 Jan 2012},
options: {},
class: Session,
embedded: false>
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong or does mongoid have a bug?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly converting the Date object to a string?

Comment: Yes, sadly it doesn't work... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to the developer of the gem and he says it is supported in rails 3.1 +
Also, we made this work by using a different syntax (similar to javascript).

```
scope :between, ->(from, to){ where(:created_at => {'$gte' =>  Time.parse(from.to_s)}).and(:created_at => {'$lte' => Time.parse((to + 1.day).to_s) - 1.second }) }
```

And it turns out this is supported in rails 3.0